# Action not found error using Struts 2

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

```
02, 2017 4:32:41 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
严重: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/F:/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/imooc_hibernate_struts/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:12:45
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:493)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5205)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/F:/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/imooc_hibernate_struts/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:12:45
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Action class [hello.World] not found - action - file:/F:/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/imooc_hibernate_struts/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:12:45
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:486)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:429)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:556)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:295)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:264)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 17 more

二月 02, 2017 4:32:41 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
严重: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
二月 02, 2017 4:32:41 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
严重: Context [/imooc_hibernate_struts] startup failed due to previous errors
二月 02, 2017 4:32:41 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
信息: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8888]
二月 02, 2017 4:32:41 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
信息: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
二月 02, 2017 4:32:41 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
信息: Server startup in 6400 ms
```

struts.xml code

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
    <struts>
        <!-- 开发模式 - ture -->
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <!-- 声明包名，并指定命名空间/hello，同时继承于struts-default。 这与我们定义一个class相类似 -->
        <package name="default" namespace="/hello" extends="struts-default">
            <!-- 设置hellostruts Action -->
            <action name="struts" class="hello.World">
                <!-- 设置V层，相对于WebContent的绝对路径 -->
                <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/hellostruts.jsp</result>
            </action>

        </package>
    </struts>
```

World.java code

[image]

library

[image]

I am a beginner. If I add `class="hello.World"`, it always tells me `action hello.World not found`, but I really created it and I don't know if it is a problem of version, and where is the problem.

I don't have the experience of reading console information, if possible, please tell me how to solve the problem. This is error which I am getting.

Comment: You had a typo on your configuration file when you obtain that stack trace Caused by: Action class [hello.Wrold] <- Should be hello.World. Fix your compilation errors (see index.jsp), redeploy and try again.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected, I hope you can help me solve this problem.

Comment: It seems that you don't have deployed your application correctly in your Tomcat. Your class is not available to the server.

Comment: I am a beginner, So I do not know what should I do. I have just encountered such a situation. I changed the class name to [hello.World], but it also prompted me action [hello.Wrold] not found. And I ran another test project, but the tip is the same as last time. But the test project's class name is [test.test]. I do not know how I should solve the problem. Can you tell me in detail? In addition, my English is not good, Please forgive me.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I think that you have to study a bit about web applications in Java. When you got a web application on your IDE and you want to test it, your application is deployed to the selected server , the server is started and then (if no problems occurs) you can access it from a webbrowser.

Comment: Your server's start failed because your class is not being deployed. I do not know the exact reason. Maybe some misconfiguration in your Eclipse or in your web server. Follow the steps in this tutorial https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have downloaded the Struts tutorial's sample code and run it. But  the console information still prompted action [hello.wrold] not found. The action class of sample  code was not [hello.wrold] but [com.journaldev.struts2.action.LoginAction]. Then I  restarted eclipse, but the prompt did not change.

Comment: I've just followed the tutorial and I got no problem running the application. I don't know which one have you followed because the one that I linked main class is com.vaannila.action.HelloWorldAction. The package is important. Have you created it? Check the Servers tab in your Eclipse and be sure that your application appears in your Tomcat server with the label [Synchronized]

Comment: Ah! Finally I've realized one of your problems! Your World class must extend org.apache.struts.action.Action. Please follow exactly the steps in a tutorial and be careful when you copy-paste code.

Comment: @RubioRic This tutorial dated Jun. 13, 12, and using Struts 1.3.10. Struts 1.x is EOL. OP is using different version of Struts. It is like Struts 2.3.x.

Comment: @RomanC You're right. My mistake. OP got me lost about what tutorial is following.

Comment: @chuhangchu your project doesn't work, you should use the latest available version of Struts. The helloworld example https://github.com/apache/struts-examples/tree/master/helloworld

Answer (score 0):

Check the presence of the compiled class in your server, in tomcat should be in `webapps/.../WEB-INF/classes/hello/World.class`. Depending on how you configured your Eclipse builder this file should be updated everytime you make changes. If the compiled file is OK I guess there's some problem with the classpath.